# How do RPC nodes and validators communicate with each other?

Tags: validator

I understand not every validator is required to have RPC enabled. Also, there are separate RPC nodes that are not validators themselves.

How is information about which transactions were submitted by clients transmitted from PRC nodes to validators?

Answer (score 2):

RPC nodes perform the exact same consensus *following* as validators. Note, *following* they do not vote or produce blocks.  So they discover nodes and relay status via gossip, receive blocks over turbine, make and serve repair requests, etc.

The one thing that they do differently is forward transactions received via RPC (via the `sendTransaction` method), to the TPU port of upcoming leaders.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. You write `The one thing that they do differently is forward transactions received via RPC (via the sendTransaction method), to the TPU port of upcoming leaders.`

What exactly is different here? I thought that also validators forward transactions received via RPC to the TPU of the upcoming leader, the same as RPC nodes do. Is my view not correct?

Answer (score 1):

RPC is the first layer of the transaction. Once you send a transaction through Solana wallet, that request goes to an RPC server. RPC server receives the transaction over HTTP, it checks the incoming request, if it is a valid Solana transaction, it converts the transaction into UDP packet and sends it to the validator. From https://solana.com/news/solana-network-upgrades

> Solana uses a custom raw UDP-based protocol to pass transactions
> between RPC nodes and the current leader. Since UDP is connectionless
> and lacks both flow control and receipt acknowledgments, there is no
> meaningful way to discourage or mitigate abusive behavior. In order to
> affect control over network traffic, Solana's transaction ingestion
> protocol are being reimplemented atop QUIC, a protocol built by
> Google, designed for fast asynchronous communication like UDP, but
> with sessions and flow control like TCP. Once adopted, there will be
> many more options available to adapt and optimize data ingestion.